# Same number of rows in oracle query

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I'm really new at PL/SQL

I am trying to make a query to display some purchases and their dates. The thing is that I'd like to ensure that the result of the query returns me some kind of group-by with the same number of rows for each date depending on the number of the largest subset.

**Here's an example on Oracle:**

```
   select date_val, cost
   from test
   order by date_val
```

Which gives me this result:

```
    date_val   cost
    03/04/2017  950907.12
    03/04/2017  10935431.88
    03/04/2017  1411410
    03/04/2017  504604380
    04/04/2017  1348410
    05/04/2017  1379000560
    05/04/2017  1208340
    05/04/2017  1735016.32
    06/04/2017  15913063.36
    06/04/2017  1383744.64
    06/04/2017  1522710
    06/04/2017  1172111669
    07/04/2017  278336734
    07/04/2017  579649.52
```

In this case, the length of the biggest subset is of 4 (dates 03 and 06), so I would like to complete the table and get something like this:

```
    date_val   cost
    03/04/2017  950907.12
    03/04/2017  10935431.88
    03/04/2017  1411410
    03/04/2017  504604380
    04/04/2017  1348410
    04/04/2017  0
    04/04/2017  0
    04/04/2017  0
    05/04/2017  1379000560
    05/04/2017  1208340
    05/04/2017  1735016.32
    05/04/2017  0
    06/04/2017  15913063.36
    06/04/2017  1383744.64
    06/04/2017  1522710
    06/04/2017  1172111669
    07/04/2017  278336734
    07/04/2017  579649.52
    07/04/2017  0
    07/04/2017  0
```

Any suggestions will be very helpful.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is the date in `date` datatype? (If not, why not?) If it is, what is the time-of-day component? In Oracle, `date` always has time-of-day component, even if it is not displayed on screen. It is possible that all your dates have the time-of-day of `00:00:00` (the usual way to make dates be "pure" dates, without time-of-day) - is that the case?

Comment: Also, if a date were missing completely (let's say there was no row for 04/04), would you still want it added to the result, four rows, each of them with cost of 0?

Comment: Hello! Yes the datatype is date but as you said, they are pure dates, without tge time-of-day. 
And for the other question, I only want to display the dates present ond the table, if 04/04 doesn't appear at all then I don't want to see it but if it has at least 1 record I want it to fill the rest records with cost 0

Answer (score 3):

Here is one method:

```
with t as (
      select date_val, cost,
             row_number() over (partition by date_val order by cost) as seqnum
      from test
     )
select d.date_val, coalesce(t.cost, 0) as cost
from (select distinct date_val from t) d cross join
     (select distinct seqnum from t) s left join
     t
     on d.date = t.date and s.seqnum = t.seqnum
order by d.date_val;
```

The idea is to add a sequence number to each row for each date.  Then, cross join each distinct date with each distinct sequence number.  That gives you the rows.  The `left join` then gives the existing information.

Comment: Thak you so much for your help! This worked very well for the thing I wanted to display! :D